# Using list functions on shelved variables

Tags: python

Disclaimer! This is a (self-assigned) homework problem.

So I'm working through the online python book "Automate the Boring Stuff" and I'm stuck on one of the challenges.

The idea is to add a function that removes an item from the shelved variables list. For reference they are stored like this:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
```

so I've tried a couple different things in order to remove the item, but neither of these works:

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    mcbShelf.keys().remove(sys.argv[2])
    print ('Trying to remove ' + sys.argv[2] + ' from the list')
```

or

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    list(mcbShelf.keys()).remove(sys.argv[2])
    print ('Trying to remove ' + sys.argv[2] + ' from the list')
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree with the list remove function?

Comment: How about `del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]`? Don't try to remove the key, remove the item from the dict, by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mcbShelf.keys()` creates a new `list`, so removing the item will have no affect on it's parent `dict`. Remove the item from the `dict` with `del`:

```
del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
```